# HTTP request sent from select element populated by Angular ng-options contains type

Tags: html, angularjs, html-select, http-request

Inside a `form`, there is a `select` element populated with `ng-options` directive of Angular. The options are strings.

```
  <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8081/process_get" method="GET">
    <select name="content" ng-model="content" ng-init="content=contents[0]" ng-options="c for c in contents"></select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
  </form>
```

The script part:

```
  <script>
  var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
  app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.contents = ["A","B","C","D"];
  });
  </script>
```

I expect the server to receive a request in the form `{"content":"B"}`. However what I receive is `{"content":"string:B"}`. If I don't use Angular:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8081/process_get" method="GET">
  <select name="content">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

The request is in the expected form `{"content":"B"}`. How should I solve this?

The server is set up using `express` of `node.js`. I'm simply logging the content of the request:

```
app.get('/process_get', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.query);
}
```

So I don't think this could be related to the server part.

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Submit"></button>`: you open an input but close a button

Comment: @Mistalis Thanks for pointing out the typo. I corrected it but the problem still exists.

Comment: Perhaps move away from `<form action="...">` and use `ng-submit` and a service to call your server API.

Comment: Just a starters tip: If you use Angular, then USE ANGULAR. Seriously angular raptures your application, its hardly compatible with pure jQuery even. Do use ng-options on your select, declare an array in your controller to feed those options and you'll be good.

Comment: ng-options is not jquery, and it's how you feed the options from an array.

Comment: @Lex Thanks! Your suggestion solved the problem. I think this can serve as a proof of Felype's tip that I should stick to Angular when the task can be done with Angular.